# Como obter id de um elemento de CRUD [CodeIgniter]

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

A minha questão é a seguinte: tenho um *CRUD* feito em `CodeIgniter`, mas as linhas da tabela não estão no formato `localhost/crud/produtos/[:num]`.

Na última coluna da tabela tem botões de ação para editar e remover, um para cada linha. Como posso obter no *controller* o id da linha onde o botão é carregado?

Pus num *input* tipo *hidden* o valor do id, e o obtive no *controller* pelo metodo `post`. Há outro método mais ágil para fazer?

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row->id; ?></th>
        <td><?php echo $row->autocarro; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row->validade)); ?></td>
        <td>
            <form method="post" type="submit" action="<?php echo base_url('sistema/edit_extintores'); ?>" style="padding-right: 4px;"> 
                <input name="id_ext" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>          
            </form>
            <form method="post" type="submit" action="<?php echo base_url('#'); ?>"> 
                <input name="id_ext" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>">
                <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>          
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

[image: Imagem]

Os dados são obtidos da tabela da BD, e eu quero ao clicar no botão como indicação 1 na imagem, obtenha o id dessa linha para pegar todas as informações respetivas a esse id da base de dados.

Comment: Coloque algum exemplo de código que você esta usando...

Comment: atualizado o post

Comment: Cara eu uso o CodeIgniter a 2 anos e não entendi sua pergunta.

 localhost/crud/produtos/[:num]. voce já fez a rota? la nas configurações de rota?
Outra você quer exibir que tipo de informação pq voce volta no seu texto de post vai pra lugar nenhum o que voce quer que faça a o editar parece ok mas o lixo não acho que voce está querendo 2 coisas diferentes voce pode fazer o edit ir para um popup e o remove para outro

Comment: o lixo ainda nao está configurado, eu so queria uma maneira de obter o id da linha da informação, sem ter que usar aquela gambiarra do input type hidden

Comment: Claro que tem como, você pode utilizar algumas formas. Utilizar método  GET no lugar de Post, você pode usar Jquery, so depende do que você quer exatamente, por que na sua pergunta você já resolveu.

Answer (score -1):

Utilize o `$row['id']`

Enquanto você estiver dentro do seu bloco `foreach` você consegue pegar esses dados.